# Why I get so many more records with not like in sql

Tags: sql, mysql

Why I get so many more records with a condition in sql?

I try to build a sql table based on another sql table. The original commands are:

```
cursor.execute('DELETE FROM Dataplace.Queue')
cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO Dataplace.Queue SELECT DISTINCT COSTCENTER, 'Pending', Null, Null FROM Dataplace.START")
```

Where the start table has the following structure:

```
Calmonth COSTCENTER    NAME VALUE
202301    0002001234    A    10
202302    0002001234    A    20
202301    0002001234    B    15
202301    0001166666    A    12
202301    0001000666    A    11
...
```

And with the original command i get 378 entries, with the output for the Queue Table:

```
Key         Status  Container Duration
0002001234  Pending NULL     NULL
0001166666  Pending NULL     NULL
0001000666  Pending NULL     NULL
```

When I run the commands:

```
cursor.execute('DELETE FROM Dataplace.Queue')
cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO Dataplace.Queue SELECT DISTINCT COSTCENTER, 'Pending', Null, Null FROM Dataplace.START WHERE NOT (COSTCENTER LIKE '000200%' OR COSTCENTER LIKE '001000%')")
```

I get an output with 577 rows. I would expect an output less then above (378-84 see the following command). What do I miss here?
The commands:

```
cursor.execute('DELETE FROM Dataplace.Queue')
cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO Dataplace.Queue SELECT DISTINCT COSTCENTER, 'Pending', Null, Null FROM Dataplace.START WHERE COSTCENTER LIKE '000200%' OR COSTCENTER LIKE '001000%'")
```

gives a output with 84 rows.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you are running against the same server, and have definitely included `DISTINCT` in the last query? The row counts you are seeing are from the select and not the delete etc? If you have 378 distinct values for cost centre in the whole table, then there is no where clause in the world that could make the same select query with distinct return more values than this.

Comment: Could there be data added between each queries? Like a shared dev server (or  even worse, a production server)

Comment: If you run the following directly against the database, do you get the same numbers as above (384, 84, 577) :   `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CostCentre), COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN COSTCENTER LIKE '000200%' OR COSTCENTER LIKE '001000%' THEN COSTCENTER END),COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN NOT (COSTCENTER LIKE '000200%' OR COSTCENTER LIKE '001000%' THEN COSTCENTER END) FROM Dataplace.START;`

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to determine the correct query to execute without the Dataset, but I'll try anyway:

If I understood, it's just a matter of conditions and operators.

Doing a

```
[...] WHERE NOT (a LIKE '%x%' OR b LIKE '%y%')
```

will basically return everything except of the names that contain both `x` and `y`.

Instead:

```
[...] WHERE (a NOT LIKE '%x%' AND b NOT LIKE '%y%')
```

should return the correct result.

You need to retrieve the `COSTCENTER`s that don't contain `'000200%'`
AND `'001000%'`.

So, the query will be:

```
cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO Dataplace.Queue SELECT DISTINCT COSTCENTER, 'Pending', Null, Null FROM Dataplace.START WHERE (COSTCENTER NOT LIKE '000200%' AND COSTCENTER NOT LIKE '001000%')")
```

Comment: Well, `NOT (A or B)` and `(NOT A and NOT B)` are the same. See [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)